# Jquery map not showing points when passing json value

Tags: jquery, json, google-maps-api-3

I'm using a jquery map script called GMap2.  I'm calling my php script via jquery/ajax and returning the marker information in json format.  The problem is that when I do this, the map points do not show up.  But if I manually add the json values, the map points work just fine.  Here is my code that calls the gmap code:

```
$('.shownearby').click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        cache:false,
        url:'path/to/php/script',
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {

            $('#showmap').gMap(
                    {
                        latitude   : data.dlat,
                        longitude  : data.dlon,
                        address    : data.daddress,
                        maptype    : 'ROADMAP',
                        zoom       : 10,
                        markers    : data.nearby
                    }

            );

        }

    });

    return false;

});
```

As you see the markers option is loading the value of nearby from the json variable data being passed back on success.  You can see an example of an entry that is returned from data.nearby below (I replaced the lat/long/html with dummy data for example purposes):

```
[{"latitude":"latva","longitude":"latlon","html":"htmlstuff"}]
```

But again when I pass this information it does not work, however if I paste the json value above that has the lat/long and html values next to markers variable directly the map point comes up just fine. Any idea what the problem is?

Here is example code of using multiple points in the gmap2 script:

```
$('#map_addresses').gMap({
    address: "Quito, Ecuador",
    zoom: 5,
    markers:[
        {
            latitude: -2.2014,
            longitude: -80.9763,
            html: "_latlng"
        },
        {
            address: "Guayaquil, Ecuador",
            html: "My Hometown"
        },
        {
            address: "Galapagos, Ecuador",
            html: "_address"
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok looks like it works now. Had to update the markers nearby value to this:

```
markers : jQuery.parseJSON(data.nearby)
```

If anyone can verify that is the correct thing to do.

Comment: Great that you got it worked out. I don't see any problem with what you have done. My guess is that when you were using the the reference `data.nearby`, you were just setting `markers` to point to a string. And even though it was a string of json, it didn't work until you parsed the json. In that case you are setting `markers` to     an array of marker data, which is what you really needed. It seems to make sense and doesn't seem to have any drawbacks.

Comment: If you feel like you answered your own question and you are satisfied with the results, it's customary to click the arrow mark next to the question to accept your own answer. It lets everyone else know that the question has been answered.

Comment: @Sean Mickey Yes I understand about accepting my own answer, however Stackoverflow makes me wait 2 days before accepting my own answer. As of right now it tells me I can accept it tomorrow. Thanks for the info though!